# Can ServiceMonitor add labels to the metric?

Tags: prometheus, prometheus-operator, opentsdb

I have a requirement to add certain labels to metric, so grafana can filter based on its value. I am wondering if there is a way to do it in the ServiceMonitor, so that I dont need to change the code in my springboot project.

Comment: Hey @Tomas were you able to get it working. I have the same requirement to add a label to all metrics in Servicemonitor

Comment: @Vaishnav Hey, I have solved the problem by adding a metricRelabelings under endpoints in ServiceMonitor.

Answer (score 2):

My final solution is adding a metricRelabelings under endpoints in ServiceMonitor.

```
apiVersion: monitoring.coreos.com/v1
kind: ServiceMonitor
metadata:
  ...
spec:
  ...
  endpoints:
    - ...
      metricRelabelings:
        - separator: ;
          regex: (.*)
          targetLabel: LABLE_NAME
          replacement: VALUE
          action: replace
```